# How can I convert and append to a slice of strings in Golang a net type variable from go-ping repository?

Tags: string, go, slice

This is the entire code, not much different from the one you can find on the git repo page.

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/go-ping"
    "time"
)

var stats = [][]string{nil}

func pinging(domain string, interval int, unit string, exit int) {

current_time:= time.Now().Local()
current_time.Format("02-01-2000")

switch unit {

case "ms":
    interval *= 1
case "sec":
    interval *= 1000
case "min":
    interval *= 6000

}

pinger, err := ping.NewPinger(domain)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

// interval between ping
pinger.Interval=time.Millisecond*time.Duration(interval)

//number of total pings
pinger.Count=exit

pinger.OnRecv = func(pkt *ping.Packet) {
    fmt.Printf("%d bytes from %s: icmp_seq=%d time=%v\n",
        pkt.Nbytes, pkt.IPAddr, pkt.Seq, pkt.Rtt)
}
pinger.OnFinish = func(stats *ping.Statistics) {
    fmt.Printf("\n--- %s ping statistics ---\n", stats.Addr)
    fmt.Printf("%d packets transmitted, %d packets received, %v%% packet loss\n",
        stats.PacketsSent, stats.PacketsRecv, stats.PacketLoss)
    fmt.Printf("round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = %v/%v/%v/%v\n",
        stats.MinRtt, stats.AvgRtt, stats.MaxRtt, stats.StdDevRtt)
}

fmt.Printf("PING %s (%s):\n", pinger.Addr(), pinger.IPAddr())
pinger.Run()
```

}

I need to convert and append to a slice of string these variables  pkt.Nbytes, pkt.IPAddr, pkt.Seq, pkt.Rtt, which are type *net from this repo https://github.com/sparrc/go-ping .

I need to do so because after that I'll print everything to a .csv
How could I do that?

Comment: What have you tried? What problems have you encountered? Please post your attempt. Aim for a [mcve].

Comment: I have tried to append the *net vars to the slice, but obviously it didn't worked, since it's not a standard type the one used for pkt.Nbytes, pkt.IPAddr, pkt.Seq, pkt.Rtt I haven't found anything useful on internet. What I'd need is to append to the slice the value as it is of those vars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [fmt.Sprintf](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf) with your example code:

```
var s []string
s = append(s, fmt.Sprintf("%d", pkt.Nbytes)
s = append(s, fmt.Sprintf("%s", pkt.IPAddr)
s = append(s, fmt.Sprintf("%d", pkt.Seq)
s = append(s, fmt.Sprintf("%v", pkt.Rtt)
```